# Regression estimates by group with p.value stars

Tags: r, dplyr, regression

I run multiple lm regressions by group, using the following command

```
by_country <- group_by(df, country)

print(do(by_country,
   tidy(lm(y ~ x*z, data=.))), n=500)
```

I added the print statement just to see the full table.
Now I would like to change the output to display stars to show the level of significance.

If I change the code to

```
df %>%
  do(by_country,
     tidy(lm(y ~ x*z, data=.))) %>%
  mutate(signif = stars.pval(p.value))
```

I get the error:
Error: Can only supply one unnamed argument, not 2.

How can I combine the group by lm and the mutate? Or is there an alternative, more convenient, way?

I am looking for the following/similar output:

```
|Country|term|estimate|std.error|stars
|:---- |:------:| -----:|-----:|-----:|
| UK  | x:z    | ... | ... | ***|
```

Answer (score 2):

`do` has been superseded. This code seems to work fine with default `mtcars` data.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars

df %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(model = list(broom::tidy(lm(disp ~ mpg*am, data = cur_data())))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(model) %>%
  mutate(signif = gtools::stars.pval(p.value))

#     cyl term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value signif
#   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> 
# 1     4 (Intercept)   -69.4     129.     -0.537  0.608    " "   
# 2     4 mpg             8.96      5.64    1.59   0.156    " "   
# 3     4 am            270.      132.      2.04   0.0806   "."   
# 4     4 mpg:am        -12.8       5.73   -2.23   0.0609   "."   
# 5     6 (Intercept)  -147.      225.     -0.653  0.561    " "   
# 6     6 mpg            18.4      11.7     1.56   0.216    " "   
# 7     6 am             64.7     682.      0.0949 0.930    " "   
# 8     6 mpg:am         -6.84     33.4    -0.205  0.851    " "   
# 9     8 (Intercept)   566.      106.      5.36   0.000320 "***" 
#10     8 mpg           -13.9       6.91   -2.00   0.0729   "."   
#11     8 am          -1203.     1736.     -0.693  0.504    " "   
#12     8 mpg:am         76.4     113.      0.678  0.513    " "
```

Answer (score 1):

Example data:

```
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(country = sample(c("A","B"),100,replace=TRUE),
x=runif(100),y=runif(100),z=runif(100))
```

You don't need to pass the data.frame:

```
by_country <- group_by(df, country)

do(by_country,
   tidy(lm(y ~ x*z, data=.))) %>%
  mutate(signif = stars.pval(p.value))
```

Or:

```
df %>%
group_by(country) %>%
do(tidy(lm(y ~ x*z, data=.))) %>%
mutate(signif = stars.pval(p.value))
```

Both gives:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   country [2]
  country term        estimate std.error statistic    p.value signif
  <fct>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl> <chr> 
1 A       (Intercept)   0.808      0.154     5.25  0.00000324 "***" 
2 A       x            -0.552      0.307    -1.80  0.0780     "."   
3 A       z            -0.491      0.326    -1.50  0.139      " "   
4 A       x:z           0.853      0.552     1.55  0.129      " "   
5 B       (Intercept)   0.0658     0.194     0.339 0.736      " "   
6 B       x             0.503      0.300     1.68  0.101      " "   
7 B       z             0.866      0.400     2.17  0.0360     "*"   
8 B       x:z          -0.857      0.609    -1.41  0.167      " "
```